# How to add hyperlink in RegisterStartupScript or in alert message?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to insert a link in RegisterStartupScript, so the result will be popup message with the link.this is my code:

```
string script = "alert(\"" + "Please go to this link " + "\");";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", script, true);
```

I tried to put the link inside the alert but the result just plain text not a link, i tried to put the link like this

```
Response.Redirect(string.Format("~/WebUI/ProductApplication/DataRegister/Inquiry.aspx"), false);
```

How to make it as hyperlink in popup message?

according to Carlos to use jQuery, i put some javascript inside the scriptmanager so the code become like this:

```
    string script = "var result = confirm('There are " + dt.Rows.Count.ToString() + " Overdue Register Data, do you want to navigate to Data Register Overdue Page?'); if(result){window.location = 'Overdue.aspx'}";
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", script, true);
```

Comment: can not put link inside alert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it will be possible. You need to use jQuery Dialog for example or change your strategy to do something like the below.

```
var link = "https://www.google.com"
var result = confirm("Do you want to navigate to: " + link + "?");
if (result)
{
    window.location = link;   
}
```

Comment: the program is using asp only, is it possible to use any sources from asp.net library in visual studio 2012?

Comment: you can probably use ajax control toolkit. they have a modal popup extension: [https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ModalPopup%20Control&referringTitle=Tutorials](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ModalPopup%20Control&referringTitle=Tutorials)

Comment: I put javascript inside the scriptmanager,and it works thank you